# Is it possible to implement Typescript class which has a protected property?

Tags: typescript, oop, ts-jest, cocoscreator

I'm trying to mock a class of a third party library which contains a `protected` property and have got an error message.

here's a small reproducible example:

```js
class WithProtected {
    protected property: number = 1
}

class Derived implements WithProtected {
    property = 3
}
```

which outputs the following error message:

```
Class 'Derived' incorrectly implements class 'WithProtected'. Did you mean to extend 'WithProtected' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Property 'property' is protected but type 'Derived' is not a class derived from 'WithProtected'.(2720)
```

I'm kinda stuck to this mocking because the third party lib is Cocos Creator and doesn't live in the `node_modules` library. The only way Typescript is working with it is because it is linked via a `path` entry in the `tsconfig.json` file of the project.

So I'm not able to use the mocking out of the box from jest.

Also, as I cannot import directly from the lib itself, I have to write a fair amount of mock without importing members directly from 'cc' but with the `import type {} from 'cc'` which doesn't allow me to `extend` said classes and implement only the mocks.

Maybe too much details on this but if I could at least find a way to `implement` a class which contains a private prop, this would probably save me!

Comment: You can extend the class to access it? It's `protected`, not `private`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. I must use `import type` statements because I don't actually have access to the class but only to an ambiant `.d.ts` file so jest throws an error because the class I try to extend (or implement) isn't to be found.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-2jqdic?file=/index.ts) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I was actually going to try something similar today :D I think this will work in the pretty messy world of Cocos Creator :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes with `private` or `protected` methods are [intentionally incompatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes) with other classes or types, even if they are [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) identical.  This is one of the few places in TypeScript where types are treated [nominally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) instead of structurally, and so the problem you're facing is considered a feature.  If you need compatibility with a `private`/`protected` property, you need your type to originate from the same declaration site.

This implies that you'll never get another `class` statement to work directly.

---

Instead, you could use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on a `class` expression to claim that your new class is compatible with the other one.  Maybe like this:

```
import type { WithProtected } from "./theLib";

const MyWithProtected = (class {
  property = 2;
} as any) as new () => WithProtected;
```

That compiles with no error (although the compiler is resistant and you need to use two type assertions to overcome its objections).  Now you have a `MyWithProtected` class constructor that the compiler believes makes instances of your imported `WithProtected` type.

And then if you need to make subclasses via `extends` you can do so:

```
class Derived extends MyWithProtected {
  property = 3;
}
```

[Codesandbox link to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-2jqdic?file=/index.ts)

Comment: Thank you for the links and explanation. These help a lot understand what is actually going on. I just used `as unknown as new () => ClassIReplicate` instead of `as any`.